# Cannot filter beautifulsoup results for images

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the URL for images on a webpage and use this code :

```
import httplib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request('URL')
for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('img')):
        if "visibility:hidden" not in link:
                print "IMAGE PATH: "+link['src']
```

And I want to filter the links to invisible images like :

```
img style="position:absolute;z-index:-3334;top:0px;left:0px;visibility:hidden;" src="https://.....
```

But I'm not able to filter on the "link" variable. If always pass.

What type is the link variable? string ? Can I convert it to string type ?
How should I do this please ?
Thank you.

Edit:
Thank you  M. Leung
I tried using the constructor you gave :
BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('img')
but this fails for me :
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "getLinksFromPage3.py", line 10, in 
    for link in BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('img')):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1522, in **init**
    BeautifulStoneSoup.**init**(self, *args, **kwargs)
    TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parse_only'

Comment: in the if statement: did you try ``link['style']`` ?

Comment: Please Share URL

Comment: In the BeautifulSoup documentation: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ you have a clear example that the catched content is a dictionary so I think that using ``link['style']`` should resolve the problem.

Comment: yes I tried with this code :
        if link['style'] and "hidden" not in link['style']:
                print "hidden found"
        else:
                print "IMAGE PATH: "+link['src']
 
and returned
if link['style'] and "hidden" not in link['style']:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 613, in __getitem__
    return self._getAttrMap()[key]
KeyError: 'style'

I guess it failed on the first link that has no img style...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tag.attrs` to get the attrs on the tag first, then filter attr. The following code work.

Also, you should define which parser is suitable for the case, a better result will be made.

```
for link in BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('img')):
    if 'style' in link.attrs:
        if "visibility:hidden" not in link['style']:
            print link['src']
    else:
        print link['src']
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll test it ASAP.
What do you mean my type of parser ? Is html.parser not the right one to use ? What do you recommend ?

Comment: BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('img')): fails for me:
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parse_only'
What version do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you M. Leung.
I had to change to bs4 as well.

```
import httplib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request('URL')

for link in BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('img')):
    if 'style' in link.attrs:
        if "visibility:hidden" not in link['style']:
            print link['src']
    else:
        print link['src']
```